# Basic doubt regarding attached circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, led-driver

[image]

Could some one give me a quick answer why voltage drop at the drain of M1 is 4.611V and not 5V. Since the N-FET is non conducting, it acts as a open. similarly the diode should also be off and open. And the voltage at the drain of M1 should have been 5V. Why is the diode dropping 400mV. Is it because of reverse leakage current ?

Comment: Why don't you actually check what the current through the diode is?

Answer (score 5):

It's not "reverse leakage current" since the FET is forward biased. Look at [the data sheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/jantx2n6764.pdf). Instead, this is what is called "zero gate voltage drain current", and for an IRF 150 this has a maximum of 25 uA at room temperature. If the load were a resistor, this wouldn't create much voltage for usable loads. However, since you're using a diode, the exponential V-I curve will drop several hundred mV at these low currents.